# Dealing with Null Character when receiving UDP in Python

Tags: python, sockets, null, udp

I Have a python script I am running to receive data over UDP from the analog inputs of an Arduino.

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "10.0.0.222"
UDP_PORT = 50000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(12) # buffer size is 32 bytes
    print len(data) #check length of data recived
    sensors = struct.unpack('>hhhhhh', data)
    print sensors
```

The Arduino is sending a packet of the 6 analog readings in a 12 byte packet. Each reading is a 16 bit integer in 2 bytes with the LSB first then the MSB. I have the script working fine till the value of one of the readings on the Arduino drops below 255. At this point the Arduino sends a null character \x00. When this happen the script will not read any more of the data and stops running. I think the problem I have is reading the UDP data into a string, I have looked at using the sock.recv_into() but have not found any examples I understand, any help or pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks
Steve

Comment: Your program works fine for me when I send it a packet containing 12 bytes that are all zero... is the problem that the Arduino is sending a packet containing only a single byte?  If so, you can handle that by checking len(data) before trying to do the struct.unpack().  FWIW strings in Python can and do contain NUL bytes at arbitrary positions (and so they can also hold arbitary binary data, as in your example); so that's not a problem.  But struct.unpack() will barf if you don't pass it the expected amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat binary data as though it was a null-terminated string, and specifically you can't use string functions to determine its length. The datagram contains the length of the data received. Surely Python provides a way of getting that from the datagram?

Comment: Strings in Python are not NUL-terminated; they can contain arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Python strings (like any other Python object) are stored by the Python interpreter as a C struct -- in this case it's a PyStringObject.  The struct contains a member variable named ob_size which is the number of bytes the object occupies.  So len() calls the C function PyString_GetSize(), which returns a value derived from the ob_size value.